# How to use data generated from builder pattern

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust and this is basically the first Rust code I'm trying to write. Below is a simplified version of the problematic code I'm working on, but the errors are exactly the same.

```
struct A {
    pub value : i32
}

impl A {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        A {value : 0}
    }
}

struct B {
    vec_a : Vec<A>
}

impl B {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        B {
            vec_a : Vec::new()
        }
    }
    pub fn create_A(&mut self) -> &mut A {
        let a = A::new();
        self.vec_a.push(a);
        let last_index = self.vec_a.len() - 1;
        &mut self.vec_a[last_index]
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut b = B::new();
    let a1 : &mut A = b.create_A();
    let a2 : &mut A = b.create_A();
    
    println!("{}, {}", a1.value, a2.value);
}
```

The code gives below compilation error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `b` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:32:23
   |
31 |     let a1 : &mut A = b.create_A();
   |                       ------------ first mutable borrow occurs here
32 |     let a2 : &mut A = b.create_A();
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
33 |     
34 |     println!("{}, {}", a1.value, a2.value);
   |                        -------- first borrow later used here
```

It seems to me that the compiler is telling me that the using of `a1` is not safe as it is generated from `b`, and yet there is another mutable borrow of `b` after `a1`, that may change `b`, so that the data in `a1` is invalid now. Am I understanding this error correctly? If so, how do I tell the compiler `a1` and `a2` are completely different part of `b` and using `a1` later on is fine?

[Code in Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=264f5bef877e8e59d0949303fc1c2517)

Comment: Are you sure you want to `create` the reference and not the owned value?

Comment: @Cerberus He tries to store the created objects in the builder, for some reason. I assume it has a reason, otherwise that's indeed what I would change.

Comment: Yes, there was a reason. In my actual code `B` is not simply a builder, it is actually a centralized data manager that contains all the actual data of instances of `A`. But now the reason is doomed along with the design...

Comment: You could achieve that if you store them as `Arc<Mutex>` or `Rc<RefCell>` in your vector, and hand them out as `Weak` pointers. Although that would have a bunch of overhead. But that's the only sound way I could think of that accomplishes what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I will check these smart pointers types and see which one suits me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes your understanding is correct. `a1` is borrowed from `b`, and while `a1` exists, you cannot modify `b`.

> If so, how do I tell the compiler a1 and a2 are completely different part of b and using a1 later on is fine?

That's wrong, and the fact that you assume it is possible shows how valuable the borrow checker is. Even in C++, your code would be undefined behaviour.

Adding an element to a vector could cause a memory reallocation, invalidating all references to elements in that vector. It's [the same in C++](https://cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/).

Therefore the compiler is right: You cannot do this. `self.vec_a.push()` will potentially invalidate your `a1` reference.

---

Even if a reallocation would not happen, your code would still be unsound.

Nothing in `b` keeps track of the references to the vector. Therefore if you **could** access `b` while `a1` (a `&mut` reference into `b`) exists, you could get another reference `&b.vec_a[0]`. Then you would have a `&mut` and a `&` reference to the same `A` object at the same time, which is forbidden/unsound.

---

What are you trying to accomplish? I'm sure there is a different programming pattern that is more suited for Rust. The one you are using right now is simply not compatible with Rust.

Comment: Praise for the awesome answer and pity for me forgetting about vector reallocation... I need to go back and think more about the whole design. It is fundamentally broken right now as internally I used raw pointer differences to get the ID (vector index) of `a*`, and the whole system relies on the ID, which is unreliable.

Comment: @Bravo Well, in that case what you *could* do without fundamentally changing your design, is that you use vector indices (not pointers but `usize`s, maybe wrapped in some struct) as IDs. They wouldn't keep the Vec borrowed, and they wouldn't change on moving the Vec either. Then, you can use those indices to create short-lived mutrefs to the Vec, when you *actually need them* (only one at a time of course - or many read only references). You just have to ensure that elements are only added but not removed from the Vec.

Comment: @FZs Yes, that is one the way. Actually an existing module on Crates that does pretty much the same thing I'm trying to do is returning IDs directly. Seems the author didn't do it without a reason. :)

Comment: @Bravo For some reason, your entire problem shouts entity-component-system to me. Maybe take a look at [`specs`](https://crates.io/crates/specs), if that somehow fits your usecase? (Of course I don't know the context, just assuming)

Comment: @Finomnis Actually it's `petgraph`. I am working on a EDA software which basically sits on a gigantic graph, using C++. And I am learning Rust in my spare time, so I thought reinventing the wheel might be a good project to me. And turns out it is, big thank to you guys, I learned something both in Rust and C++.